# How to change the Id of row dynamically in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mysql, jsp

This is my simple HTML page. In this program when I press enter to create dynamic row, it creates a new row.

But the problem is that I want to change the id of every row like `search1`,`search2`,`search3`.

For checking this, I show id in alert, but only first row id show in alert box. When I inspect the page and check the id of second row, it changed the id.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <link type="text/css" href="Bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
       
        <br><br>
    <center>
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">

        <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table-responsive table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>No.</th>
            <th>Name</th> 
            <th>Price</th> 
        </tr>   
        </thead>    
        
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">1</td>
                <td><input type="text" class="inputs searchName" name="pname_1" size="15" id="search1"/></td>    
                <td><input type="text" class="inputs lst" size="15" /></td>    

            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </center>
        
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Bootstrap/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="Bootstrap/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

**This is the JQuery that are create dynamic rows:**

```
 $(document).keypress(
    function(event){
     if (event.which == '13') {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
});

var i = $('table tr').length;
var count=0;
$(document).on('keyup', '.lst', function(e) 
{
  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if (code == 13) 
  {
    count = $('table tr').length;     
    
    html = '<tr>';
    html += '<td align="center">'+ i +'</td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" class="inputs searchName"  size="15" name="pname_' + i + '" id="search'+i+'" /></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" class="inputs lst"  size="15" /></td>';
            
    html += '</tr>';
    
    $('table').append(html);
    $(this).focus().select();
    i++;
  }
});

$(document).on('keydown', '.inputs', function(e) {
  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if (code==13) {
    var index = $('.inputs').index(this) + 1;
    $('.inputs').eq(index).focus();
  }
});

      $('.searchName').keyup(function()
      {
          var id=$(this).attr("id");
          alert(id);
          
      });
```

Comment: when you bind the `keyup` function to your searchname elements, there's only one in the page, so only one will be binded to that function.

Comment: @GiulioAmbrogi you are correct, but you are forgetting that there is new dynamic inputs being created so at first there is one, but there will be more rows created.

Comment: @CesarBielich No, I am aware of that.
What I am telling you is that you are running that `keyup` function **only once** when there is only 1 element. If you create 100 more elements **after** that, you'll need to bind that keyup function to them as well.

Comment: This simple HTML page patched by jsp

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use **$(document).on** instead of $('.searchName').keyup function

Try the following code

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.searchName', function() {    
  var id=$(this).attr("id");
  alert(id);    
});
```

Here is the working jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/r9hpyabh/

Answer (score 0):

Had to change some of your code, found many errors , but I think I have you squared away.

First you needed to define your html var so I added `var html;`

Second your `html` var was duplicating your previous html so you need to blank it out with each new `$(document).on('keyup', '.lst', function(e) {` so I added `html = '';`

Third you needed to change your `$('.searchName').keyup(function() {` to `$(document).on('keyup', '.searchName', function() {` to account for your dynamic content.

**Remember** that whenever you are dealing with dynamic content you need to use `$(document).on('event', 'class or id', function() {` to be able to capture that dynamic content.

```js
var i = $('table tr').length;
var count = 0;
var html;
$(document).on('keyup', '.lst', function(e) {
  html = '';
  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if (code == 13) {
    count = $('table tr').length;

    html += '<tr>';
    html += '<td align="center">' + i + '</td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" class="inputs searchName"  size="15" name="pname_' + i + '" id="search' + i + '" /></td>';
    html += '<td><input type="text" class="inputs lst"  size="15" /></td>';

    html += '</tr>';

    $('tbody').append(html);
    $(this).focus().select();
    i++;
  }
});

$(document).on('keydown', '.inputs', function(e) {
  var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
  if (code == 13) {
    var index = $('.inputs').index(this) + 1;
    $('.inputs').eq(index).focus();
  }
});

$(document).on('keyup', '.searchName', function() {
  var id = $(this).attr("id");
  alert(id);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <center>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8">

          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table-responsive table-bordered">
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>No.</th>
                  <th>Name</th>
                  <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>

              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td align="center">1</td>
                  <td><input type="text" class="inputs searchName" name="pname_1" size="15" id="search1" /></td>
                  <td><input type="text" class="inputs lst" size="15" /></td>

                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </center>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should learn how jquery works.  It's all about selectors. The selector which is applied on the `id`  selects a zero or one element. The selector which is applied on the class selects more elements. You should read the FAQ: [How do I select an item using class or ID?](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-item-using-class-or-id/).

After reading this article I came to idea what is wrong with your code.